# How to omit page numbers for unnumbered entries such as "Abstract" in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to omit the pagenumbers just for the words in blue.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pgf} 
\usepackage{tikz, pgf} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[upright]{fourier} 
\usepackage{tkz-graph} 
\usepackage{tkz-berge} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10} 
...
\chapter*{R\'{E}SUM\'{E}} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{R\'{E}SUM\'{E}}
...
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "numbers just for the words". Are you maybe thinking about page numbers?

Comment: yes, i mean the page numbers of those in blue

Comment: Please tell us more about the basic structure of your LaTeX document. E.g., which document class do you employ? Which command is used to generate the headers “résumé”, “abstract”, etc? And, do you employ any packages (`titletoc`?, `tocloft`?) to help generate the table of content?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz, pgf}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}

Comment: for exemple.. \chapter*{R\'{E}SUM\'{E}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{R\'{E}SUM\'{E}}

Comment: i don't employ those packages (titletoc,tocloft)

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I've taken the liberty of copying the code snippets into the body of your query, where they'll be far more likely to be noticed by other readers.

Comment: thanks.. but what should i do to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, the `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{...}` instruction automatically inserts a page number. What you need to use is the lower-level `\addtocontents{toc}{...}` instruction. Because this instruction is very low-level, one needs to be very explicit about every single item that's supposed to be typeset in this way. In the following example, I've created a "wrapper macro" called `\tocentry` that simplifies the use of `\addtocontents`. That way, instead of having to write

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\noindent\protect\textbf{\MakeUppercase{Résumé}}\par\vspace*{1\baselineskip}}
```

you can simply write

```
\tocentry{Résumé}
```

And so on for the other unnumbered-chapter entries.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%\usepackage{pgf} % (don't load 'pgf' twice)
\usepackage{tikz, pgf} 
\usepackage{tkz-graph} 
\usepackage{tkz-berge} 

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
%\usepackage{amsfonts} % (is loaded automatically by 'amssymb')
\usepackage{amsmath} 
%\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10} % (that's the default value)

\newcommand{\tocentry}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\noindent% 
  \protect\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}\par%
  \vspace*{1\baselineskip}}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter*{Résumé} 
\tocentry{Résumé}
\dots

\clearpage
\chapter*{Abstract} 
\tocentry{Abstract}
\dots

\clearpage
\chapter*{Résumé en Arabe} 
\tocentry{Résumé en Arabe}
\dots

\clearpage
\chapter*{Remerciements} 
\tocentry{Remerciements}
\dots

\clearpage
\chapter*{Dédicace} 
\tocentry{Dédicace}
\dots

\clearpage
\chapter*{Introduction} 
\tocentry{Introduction}
\dots

\clearpage
\addtocounter{page}{9} % just for this example
\chapter{Définitions et notations basiques} 
\section{Définitions et notations}
\subsection{Terminologie}
\dots

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. that's work